# How to get multiple element id's that have a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of items being created dynamically that a user can select. In which case the class "selected" is added.

```
<li id="test1" class="myElement selected"></li>
<li id="test2" class="myElement"></li>
<li id="test3" class="myElement"></li>
<li id="test4" class="myElement selected"></li>
<li id="test5" class="myElement selected"></li>
<li id="test6" class="myElement"></li>
```

How can I get the id's of all the elements that have the "selected" class onclick?

Comment: As an array `$('.selected').map((i, e) => e.id)`

Comment: @E.Sundin nice and simple (though I'd use `'.selected[id]'`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) with the selector `.selected[id]`. That is, all elements with class `selected` that **also** have an `id` attribute.

```js
const elementsWithSelectedClass = document.querySelectorAll('.selected[id]')
const selectedElementIds = Array.from(elementsWithSelectedClass) // convert to array
    .map(el => el.id) // map to an array of id values

console.info(selectedElementIds)
```

```html
<ul style="list-style:none">
<li id="test1" class="myElement selected"></li>
<li id="test2" class="myElement"></li>
<li id="test3" class="myElement"></li>
<li id="test4" class="myElement selected"></li>
<li id="test5" class="myElement selected"></li>
<li id="test6" class="myElement"></li>
</ul>
```

This will provide you with an array of `id` values.

I'm using [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to convert the [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) returned from `querySelectorAll` to an array so I can use the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method.

Comment: This could have better readability. The prototype path works but it may not be so clear as to what it does. I propose `Array.from(nodeList).map` instead and to clarify why the conversion is needed.

Comment: @E.Sundin nice. I'm not used to `Array.from` yet

Comment: Why you didn't use filter here?

Comment: @Mamun why filter? The query selector returns only the elements OP wants

Comment: I think map() is replaceable here with filter(). filter() is also a higher order function which works with arrays.

Comment: @Mamun Absolutely not. OP wants the `id` attribute values for the `.selected` elements and that's exactly what `map` is doing. I fail to see how the same could be achieved with `filter`

Comment: @Phil, yes you are right. in case of returning customize object, map() is the right option. Thanks.

Comment: @Mamun I still have no idea what you're talking about. It's returning an array of strings, nothing more

Comment: Thanks for the input guys. @Phil it only seems to work if "myElement" already has the class "selected". If it's added later (when the user clicks on it) it doesn't update.

Comment: @Tiago the idea is you run this in the click handler (after the "selected" class is added)

Comment: @Phil silly me, you're absolutely right. Thanks for your help (extended to all who answered)

Answer (score 1):

with jQuery

```
$(".myElement").each(function(index, element) {
    if(element.hasClass("selected")) {
        console.log(element.attr("id"));
        // or
        // console.log($(this).attr("id"));
    }
});
```

If you don't use jQuery please leave a comment here

Comment: What is the point of the `if`? You might just use `.myElement.selected` as the selector

Comment: @E.Sundin as this question seems to come from someone who doesn't know so much javascript (so is jQuery) i try to keep it as much simple as possible, it's not the best way but anyone who know's jquery's name can understand it

Comment: The thing is, you've provided more logic and complexity to the code than necessary. This is not *as much simple as possible*.

Comment: @E.Sundin so `.myElement.selected` is different from `.myElement .selected` how can a novice tell??

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [];
$(".myElement").click(function() {

  if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {

    arr.push($(this).attr('id'))
  }
  console.log(arr)

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="test1" class="myElement selected"></li>
<li id="test2" class="myElement"></li>
<li id="test3" class="myElement"></li>
<li id="test4" class="myElement selected"></li>
<li id="test5" class="myElement selected"></li>
<li id="test6" class="myElement"></li>
```

Use `.hasClass` to check if the item has the specific class

Answer (score 0):

```
<li id="test1" class="myElement selected"></li>
<li id="test2" class="myElement"></li>
<li id="test3" class="myElement"></li>
<li id="test4" class="myElement selected"></li>
<li id="test5" class="myElement selected"></li>
<li id="test6" class="myElement"></li>

<script>

$(".selected").each(function () {

 console.log($(this).attr("id"))
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this jQuery code:

```js
var selected =$('.selected');
selected.each(function(){
  console.log(this.id);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="test1" class="myElement selected"></li>
<li id="test2" class="myElement"></li>
<li id="test3" class="myElement"></li>
<li id="test4" class="myElement selected"></li>
<li id="test5" class="myElement selected"></li>
<li id="test6" class="myElement"></li>
```

If you don't want to use jQuery, you can try with JS only:

```js
var selected = document.getElementsByClassName('selected');
for (var i=0; i<selected.length; i++){
  console.log(selected[i].id);
}
```

```html
    <li id="test1" class="myElement selected"></li>
    <li id="test2" class="myElement"></li>
    <li id="test3" class="myElement"></li>
    <li id="test4" class="myElement selected"></li>
    <li id="test5" class="myElement selected"></li>
    <li id="test6" class="myElement"></li>
```